# What is the difference between mobile application testing and web application testing

Tags: testing, mobile, web, adhoc, smoke

please friends help me out

1) what is the difference between mobile application testing and web application testing?

2) what is adhoc testing?

3) differences between sanity and smoke testing

Comment: You may want to search around first about these topics... come to your own conclusions from there, and then ask more specific questions in the near future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for mobile application testing we will have to handle some specificities like playing around with touch interface, the different sensors of the phone , connectivity quality etc. This is a very broad topic. I would recommend to follow [this blog](http://dnlkntt.wordpress.com/)
2. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_testing) is your friend
3. You can find some definitions [there](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/smoke-testing-and-sanity-testing-difference/) but I think it does not really matter so much. Most of the people don't make the difference between the two terms. Just think of it as "quick tests to get an idea on the overall quality of my SUT" or "is it broken or can I go on and do more in-depth testing".